# I cannot mount nfs

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, nfs

I have a development board with my own Linux distribution created using Yocto Project and a laptop with Ubuntu. I would like the development board to be a server and the laptop to be a client.

On the development board I created a directory `/nfsserver` which I want to mount to `/mnt/nfsclient` on Ubuntu.

A content of `/etc/exports` is as follows:

```
/nfsserver clientIP(rw,no_root_squash,sync)
```

`rpcinfo -p | grep nfs` on the server and `rpcinfo -p serverIP | grep nfs` on the client shows:

```
 100003    2   tcp   2049  nfs
```

`showmount -e` on the server shows:

```
/nfsserver clientIP
```

and `showmount -e serverIP` on the client shows:

```
Export list for serverIP:
/nfsserver clientIP
```

When I try to use `sudo mount -V 2 -t nfs serverIP:/nfsserver /mnt/nfsclient`
I get the following output:

```
mount from util-linux 2.31.1 (libmount 2.31.1: selinux, btrfs, assert, debug)
```

`df -h` shows no new entry.

What can be the cause of my problem with mounting nfs?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Try (temporarily) disabling your firewall, and turning off SELinux if enabled (unlikely on Ubuntu).  If either of these things help you know where to look.

Comment: this is a cross-post ( https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/617380/i-cannot-mount-nfs ) I already wrote a comment there telling: `-V` displays the version and exits.